# Steam locomotive in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

In zsh, when I type `ls`, it lists the files in the directory, as I would expect it to. However, when I type `sl` zsh does not ASK whether I want a steam locomotive to roll across my screen. It simply autocorrects to `ls` with no way to actually run the program `sl`. This is very annoying, how do I tell zsh that sl really means sl?

It's worth noting that zsh does NOT *ask* if I want it corrected (unlike the usual auto-correct), it seems to be an alias. However, I can't figure out where the alias is. (which file)

Comment: This is probably an alias in your zsh config file, maybe `~/.zshrc`. It would look something like this: `alias sl=ls`. That's bash syntax. I'm assuming that zsh syntax is at least similar. Just delete or comment-out that line and re-open zsh.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the question referenced is for non-zealous autocorrect, which asks first. This is very zealous, and I can't find the alias used.

Comment: `which sl` will tell you, if `sl` is an alias, a function, or indeed a executable...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` or `=` to temporarily disable alias expansion:

```
\sl
=sl
```

Also, you can use

```
disable -a sl
```

to temprorarily disable alias `sl`.

But probably easiest is to search your files like `~/.zshrc` where alias `sl` is defined and comment it out.

Comment: `\sl` works, but I can't find any alias for it in `.zshrc` (it sources `~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`, but I couldn't find it in that either)

Comment: Some shells automatically source a file in /etc. I don't know about zsh. Look for something like /etc/zshrc.